# PyTorch shows the error " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'zero_' " when calling the zero_ method

Tags: pytorch

Can someone please answer why my code is showing an error.
Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(0)

a = torch.rand((1, 3), requires_grad = True)
w1 = torch.rand((3, 3), requires_grad = True)
w2 = torch.rand((3, 1), requires_grad = True)

d = torch.matmul(torch.matmul(a, w1), w2)

L = (10 - d)

L.backward()

w1 = w1 - w1.grad*0.001
w1.grad.zero_()
```

Error:
AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'zero_'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```py
w1 = w1 - w1.grad*0.001
```

is reassigning `w1`, so afterwards `w1` no longer refers to the same tensor it did before. To maintain all the internal state of `w1` (e.g. the `.grad` member) you must update `w1` in place. Since this is a leaf tensor we also need to disable construction of the computation graph.

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    w1.sub_(w1.grad * 0.001)
```

Comment: This code is used everywhere... why sometimes it doesn't work??
w1 = w1 - w1.grad*0.001